# No mouse on installation attempt on old iMac

Tags: dual-boot, usb-installation, magic-mouse

I am trying to set up a dual-boot (OSX/Ubuntu) system on an old iMac using a bootable USB drive with the installation distro. I can boot from the USB drive into Ubuntu 18.04, but the iMac seems to have lost sight of the mouse. The mouse has new batteries, works fine in OSX, and even allowed me to select the correct EFI boot partition on startup. I've tried the USB drive in different slots. However, once Ubuntu is loaded, I have no use of the mouse in order to finish the installation.

My best guess is that I'm missing a driver that will allow Ubuntu to see my wireless (Magic) mouse. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Once I'm in Ubuntu, my only option is a hard shutdown. The iMac I'm using is:

- iMac, 21.5", Mid 2010
- 3.2 GHz Intel Core i3
- ATI Radeon HD 5670 512 Mb

Comment: You should research what is required to use the apple proprietary mouse on another operating system.  Do you need a dongle?  Do you need to pair it as a Bluetooth device? Etc... You should also connect a different mouse to see if the issue persists

Comment: If you can get a terminal in the live Ubuntu session (Ctrl+Alt+T) type `lsmod | grep magic` and let us know the result. Then type `sudo shutdown now` rather than use the power button.

Comment: Interestingly, the wireless keyboard is also not recognized (something I didn't test earlier). I plugged in another keyboard, ran the lsmod command, and came up with nothing.

Comment: Thanks, @Nmath, you were spot on. It was a matter of bluetooth pairing both the keyboard and the mouse.  I had to plug a keyboard in to get it to recognize my wireless keyboard (using `bluetoothctl`). Once I had the keyboard, it was just a matter of pairing the mouse. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to first register, trust, and pair the wireless keyboard to bluetooth using [this advice](https://freewisdoms.com/apple-wireless-keyboard-on-ubuntu/). Once the keyboard was paired, it was a simple matter of walking through basically the same process with the wireless mouse. Thanks to @Nmath for the hint.